# Laravel Artisan - try/catch not working

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

**Solved - try/catch statement fine, error reported was elsewhere in code**

I've written an Artisan command which needs to log and continue past any failures of `file_get_contents()` - Internal server errors are a common one.

I have this in a Controller method:

```
try {
    $img_data = file_get_contents($url);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error with ' . $image->id . ' ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    return false;
}
```

However although the message is output correctly, it then dies with:

```
[ErrorException]            
Undefined variable: errors
```

How can I bypass Laravel's error handler completely for this code only? (if that is the problem…)

Comment: None of the code here attempts to use a variable called `$errors`. The princess is in another castle, Mario. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for more details on the error, including the line and file it's triggered by.

Comment: @ceejayoz Got it, thank you. Try/catch working but it was a closure elsewhere, called afterwards, that was lacking a `use($error)`…

Comment: That'll do it! Glad I could help.